# Bouncy Castle Maven dependencies for OIOSAML

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle, saml-2.0, opensaml

Project **[OIOSAML](https://svn.softwareborsen.dk/oiosaml.java/sp/trunk/docs/index.html)** uses **[Bouncy Castle API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouncy_Castle_(cryptography))**, managed by [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).

Part of ivi.xml:

```
...
<dependency org="org.bouncycastle" name="bcprov-jdk15on" rev="1.49" conf="*->*,!sources,!javadoc"/>
<dependency org="org.bouncycastle" name="bcpkix-jdk15on" rev="1.49" conf="*->*,!sources,!javadoc"/>
...
```

I use [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) with the same dependencies. Part of pom.xml:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
</dependency>
...
```

However, I can't found fields `subjectKeyIdentifier` and `authorityKeyIdentifier` in `X509Extension` class.

Part of `SecurityHelper` class:

```
package dk.itst.oiosaml.security;

public class SecurityHelper {
...
    public static X509Certificate generateCertificate(Credential credential, String entityId) throws Exception {
        ...
        gen.addExtension(X509Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, new JcaX509ExtensionUtils().createSubjectKeyIdentifier(credential.getPublicKey()));
        gen.addExtension(X509Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, new JcaX509ExtensionUtils().createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(credential.getPublicKey()));
        ...
    }
}
```

`X509Extension` class:

```
package org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509;

public class X509Extension {
    boolean critical;
    org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString value;

    public X509Extension(org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERBoolean derBoolean, org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString asn1OctetString) { /* compiled code */ }

    public X509Extension(boolean b, org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString asn1OctetString) { /* compiled code */ }

    public boolean isCritical() { /* compiled code */ }

    public org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString getValue() { /* compiled code */ }

    public int hashCode() { /* compiled code */ }

    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) { /* compiled code */ }

    public static org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Object convertValueToObject(org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extension x509Extension) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Which version of Bouncy Castle API need to use to work with OIOSAML?

Comment: `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extension` is deprecated in favor of `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension` but still present in the BC 1.49 and BC 1.50, and the fields mentioned in the question are also present. What do you mean by "can't found these fields"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's org.bouncycastle-bcprov-jdk15.jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
    <version>1.46</version>
</dependency>
```